# Running setup.py installation - Relative module names not supported

Tags: python, setuptools

When trying to run `develop` or `install` task of `setuptools` I am getting the `Relative module names not supported` error.

The command run is `$ python -m setup.py develop`

My `setup.py` script is pretty simple with one entry point:

```
setup(
    name='foo',
    version='1.2.3',
    # ...
    include_package_data=True,
    packages=find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'foo = somepkg.somemodule:mainfunc'
        ]
    },
    install_requires=['requests',],
    setup_requires=['pytest-runner'],
    tests_require=['pytest', 'betamax', 'flexmock']
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was solved by not running `setup.py` as a module, i.e. running

```
$ python setup.py develop
```

instead of

```
$ python -m setup.py develop
```